# Issue with FSL installation on ubuntu

Tags: boot, command-line, drivers, software-installation, python

I need to work on FSL and I'm trying to install it on Ubuntu 18.04 shell in Windows 10.

I used `python "/mnt/c/Users/user/Downloads/fslinstaller.py"`, which seems to work fine until Stage 2 where it produces this error:

```
"/usr/local/fsl/etc/fslconf/fslpython_install.sh: line 245:   703 Killed                  FSLDIR=$fsl_dir "${miniconda_bin_dir}/conda" env create -f "${script_dir}/fslpython_environment.yml" 2>> "${miniconda_install_log}"
       704 Done                    | ${script_dir}/progress.sh 400 ${quiet} >> "${miniconda_install_log}"

----- ERROR -----
Failed to create FSL Python environment - see /tmp/fslpythonlOs4/fslpython_miniconda_installer.log for details

Post install setup failed"
```

I have run  "less /tmp/fslpythonlOs4/fslpython_miniconda_installer.log" and I obtained "Installing FSL conda distribution into /usr/local/fsl/fslpython --2022-05-04 19:04:53-- repo.anaconda.com/miniconda/Miniconda3-latest-Linux-x86_64.sh Resolving repo.anaconda.com (repo.anaconda.com)... 104.16.130.3, 104.16.131.3, 2606:4700::6810:8303, ... Connecting to repo.anaconda.com (repo.anaconda.com)|104.16.130.3|:443... connected. HTTP request sent, awaiting response... 200 OK Length: 75660608 (72M) [application/x-sh] Saving to: ‘/tmp/fslpythoncXzc/fslpython_miniconda_installer.sh'

Your help is well appreciated, I'm really stuck in this step and need to move forward.

Thank you very much.
Abir.

Comment: so did you do as suggested and *"see /tmp/fslpythonlOs4/fslpython_miniconda_installer.log for details"* ?

Comment: Yes, I see it but I didn't undrestand the problem !! I tried to read it but permission denied.

Comment: How exactly did you try to read it? Did you try `less /tmp/fslpythonlOs4/fslpython_miniconda_installer.log` or `tail /tmp/fslpythonlOs4/fslpython_miniconda_installer.log` for example?

Comment: yes I have run "less /tmp/fslpythonlOs4/fslpython_miniconda_installer.log" and I obtained "Installing FSL conda distribution into /usr/local/fsl/fslpython
--2022-05-04 19:04:53--  https://repo.anaconda.com/miniconda/Miniconda3-latest-Linux-x86_64.sh
Resolving repo.anaconda.com (repo.anaconda.com)... 104.16.130.3, 104.16.131.3, 2606:4700::6810:8303, ...
Connecting to repo.anaconda.com (repo.anaconda.com)|104.16.130.3|:443... connected.
HTTP request sent, awaiting response... 200 OK
Length: 75660608 (72M) [application/x-sh]
Saving to: ‘/tmp/fslpythoncXzc/fslpython_miniconda_installer.sh'

Comment: Please [edit] that information into your question

Comment: It's done. Hope we will find a solution. Thank you once again.

Answer (score 2):

This happened to me as well on FSL 6.0.3 using Bash on Ubuntu on Windows. FSL requires Python2.7 for proper installation of fslinstaller.py. See output of python --version. If anything other than Python 2.7.x:

- sudo apt-get remove fsl
- sudo apt update
- sudo apt install python2.7
- cd ~/Downloads [or directory where fslinstaller.py is]
- sudo python2.7 fslinstaller.py

Python env successfully created, allowing me to use the GUI versions of Feat and Melodic; where previously only the command line versions were functional.